# How to navigate promises?

Tags: node.js, promise

I want to get a promises 2nd item. I have tried doing `Promise.first(2)` but it returns `undefined` the same with `Promise.last(-3)`. I have looked at `Promise.race()` and `Promise.any()`, but it donesn't look like what i need. It would be nice if its possible to do it like this..

```js
const Promise = await // Promise
for (item in Promise) {
    console.log('Promise is ' + Promise.first(item));
    
}
```

is there a way to get a specific item?

the promise holds multiple of theese items with diffrent values

```
Message {
channelId: '873969937230757938',
guildId: '873965279665860628',
deleted: false,
id: '905766388323467275',
type: 'DEFAULT',
system: false,
content: '',
author: User {
id: '530032883486687243',
bot: false,
system: false,
flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 128 },
username: 'Johnathan',
discriminator: '7301',
avatar: '8573a365f3c81903bb343bc9c2cd2c32'
},
pinned: false,
tts: false,
nonce: null,
embeds: [],
components: [],
attachments: Collection(0) [Map] {},
stickers: Collection(0) [Map] {},
createdTimestamp: 1636021935302,
editedTimestamp: 1636039356685,
reactions: ReactionManager { message: [Circular *1] },
mentions: MessageMentions {
everyone: false,
users: Collection(0) [Map] {},
roles: Collection(0) [Map] {},
_members: null,
_channels: null,
    crosspostedChannels: Collection(0) [Map] {},
repliedUser: null
},
webhookId: null,
  groupActivityApplication: null,
applicationId: null,
activity: null,
flags: MessageFlags { bitfield: 0 },
reference: null,
interaction: null
```

Comment: A promise does not have items. It is a placeholder [for a result that is not yet ready](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You need to [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) it to get the result. If the result is an array then use it as usual.

Comment: Please add examples of the value that Promise variable holds

Answer (score 0):

The Promise doesn't contain a value itself, it's a promise of a future data

Here a couple of example of how you can retrieve data from it

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve) => { // just a promise that return value after 1 second 
 setTimeout(() => resolve([1, 2, 3]), 1000)
})

async function readDataFromPromise(promise) {
  const data = await promise
  console.log('from function', data)
}

promise.then(data => console.log('from then', data))

readDataFromPromise(promise)
```